# error : AngularFireDatabase, @angular/fire/database-deprecated issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular7

Unable to implement Router guard for Admin. In Firebase database I'm adding application related property 'isAdmin:true'. When I'm trying to retrieve those app data I'm getting error in CanActivate like 'Incorrectly implement CanActivate Interface'.

I'm using,

FirebaseObjectObservable from '@angular/fire/database-deprecated. b'cause I don't know how to work with AngularFireObject(user.service.ts)

SwitchMap and Map from Rxjs to retrieve the application related data in firebase(AdminGuard.ts).Error: CanActivate Incorrectly implements Interface. Everythings looks fine I don't know what's going on with the code.

In Browser console.

> ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserService ->
>   AngularFireDatabase]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[UserService -> AngularFireDatabase]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFireDatabase!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (core.js:717)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:954)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (core.js:795)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:954)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:898)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (core.js:795)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:17656)
>       at _createClass (core.js:17701)

I tried to work with **AngularFireObject**. But I don't know how to use that to retrieve the app related data. That's why I'm using deprecated one FirebaseObjectObservable. All I've installed latest one. Only this FirebasaeObjectObservable was the deprecated one.

AdminGuard.ts

```
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Adminguard implements CanActivate{

  constructor(private auth:AuthService, private userService: UserService){}

  CanActivate(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.auth.user$
     .switchMap(user => this.userService.get(user.uid))
     .map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin);
  }

}
```

user.service.ts

```
 import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable } from '@angular/fire/database-deprecated';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase';
    import { AppUser } from './models/app-user';


    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class UserService {

      constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

      save(user: firebase.User){
        this.db.object('/users/'+ user.uid).update({
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email
        })
      }

      get(uid: string) : FirebaseObjectObservable<AppUser>{
        return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
      }

    }
```

appuser.ts

```
export interface AppUser{
  name : string,
  email: string,
  isAdmin: boolean
}
```

I expect to implement the router guard successfully by retrieve the application data which I've created manually in firebase. Based on that data I've to navigate.